# Fitting bootstrap col width to content width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout

I am building a footer for a modal, and one of the buttons is a form. What I want to achieve is to have the first four buttons to the left, and the last one to the right. I want the behavior bootstrap 4 provides with the col-{brkpt}-auto classes, but using bootstrap 3.

Code:

```
<!-- Footer Default -->
<div id="iAModalFooterDefault" class="container-fluid animated fadeInRight" style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <div class="row">

    <!-- Button: Attach Files -->
    <div id="modalAttachFilesDiv" class="col-xs-auto">
      <button id="modalAttachFilesBTN" class="btn btn-primary stripBorder disabled" onclick="attachFiles()">
        Attach Files
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Button (form): Upload External Audit -->
    <div id="modalContentDiv" class="col-xs-auto">
      <form id="modalContentForm" style="width: 180px;">
        <label id="modalUploadExternalAuditBTN" class="btn btn-primary stripBorder disabled">
          Upload External Audit
          <input type="hidden" name="modalUploadExternalAuditINPUT" id="modalUploadExternalAuditINPUT" type="file">
        </label>
        <input type="hidden" name="reportId" id="reportIdContentForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="reportStateId" id="reportStateIdContentForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="reportName" id="reportNameContentForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="reportSectorId" id="reportSectorIdContentForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="reportTypeId" id="reportTypeIdContentForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="reportAuditorId" id="reportAuditorIdContentForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="reportStartDate" id="reportStartDateContentForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="reportEndDate" id="reportEndDateContentForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="reportCriteria" id="reportCriteriaContentForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="reportReach" id="reportReachContentForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="reportSummary" id="reportSummaryContentForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="reportConclusions" id="reportConclusionsContentForm">
      </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Button: Send -->
    <div id="modalSendDiv" class="col-xs-auto">
      <button id="modalSendBTN" class="btn btn-primary stripBorder disabled" onclick="send()">
        Send
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Button: Save -->
    <div id="modalSaveDiv" class="col-xs-auto">
      <button id="modalSaveBTN" class="btn btn-primary stripBorder" onclick="save()">
        Save
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Button: Cancel -->
    <div id="modalCancelDiv" class="pull-right col-xs-auto">
      <button id="modalCancelBTN" class="btn btn-default" onclick="cancel()">
        Cancel
      </button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DVHeld/52VtD/16101/)

Comment: col-xs-auto isn't a Bootstrap class

Comment: @paddyfields: Then what's this? https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#variable-width-content

Comment: You're referencing the css for Bootstrap 3 in your JS Fiddle, and using markup for Bootstrap 4

Comment: OK, then the question is how can I achieve the same result in bootstrap 3. Updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your fiddle had bootstrap 4 CSS and bootstrap 2 JS. I changed it to use 3.3.7 CSS and JS.

You can do two things to get this working:

1. Wrap all of your buttons except for Cancel in a div with `col-xs-10`, and add a class adding `display: inline-block` to it so the buttons are on one line.
2. Make your Cancel button div have `col-xs-2` to use the remaining 2 of 12 columns.

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ugsjn0qf/)

CSS

```
.inline-block > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML

```
<!-- Footer Default -->
<div id="iAModalFooterDefault" class="container-fluid animated fadeInRight" style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-10 inline-block">
      <!-- Button: Attach Files -->
      <div id="modalAttachFilesDiv" class="">
        <button id="modalAttachFilesBTN" class="btn btn-primary stripBorder disabled" onclick="attachFiles()">
          Attach Files
        </button>
      </div>

      <!-- Button (form): Upload External Audit -->
      <div id="modalContentDiv" class="">
        <form id="modalContentForm">
          <label id="modalUploadExternalAuditBTN" class="btn btn-primary stripBorder disabled">
            Upload External Audit
            <input type="hidden" name="modalUploadExternalAuditINPUT" id="modalUploadExternalAuditINPUT" type="file">
          </label>
          <input type="hidden" name="reportId" id="reportIdContentForm">
          <input type="hidden" name="reportStateId" id="reportStateIdContentForm">
          <input type="hidden" name="reportName" id="reportNameContentForm">
          <input type="hidden" name="reportSectorId" id="reportSectorIdContentForm">
          <input type="hidden" name="reportTypeId" id="reportTypeIdContentForm">
          <input type="hidden" name="reportAuditorId" id="reportAuditorIdContentForm">
          <input type="hidden" name="reportStartDate" id="reportStartDateContentForm">
          <input type="hidden" name="reportEndDate" id="reportEndDateContentForm">
          <input type="hidden" name="reportCriteria" id="reportCriteriaContentForm">
          <input type="hidden" name="reportReach" id="reportReachContentForm">
          <input type="hidden" name="reportSummary" id="reportSummaryContentForm">
          <input type="hidden" name="reportConclusions" id="reportConclusionsContentForm">
        </form>
      </div>

      <!-- Button: Send -->
      <div id="modalSendDiv" class="">
        <button id="modalSendBTN" class="btn btn-primary stripBorder disabled" onclick="send()">
          Send
        </button>
      </div>

      <!-- Button: Save -->
      <div id="modalSaveDiv" class="">
        <button id="modalSaveBTN" class="btn btn-primary stripBorder" onclick="save()">
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Button: Cancel -->
    <div id="modalCancelDiv" class="pull-right col-xs-2">
      <button id="modalCancelBTN" class="btn btn-default" onclick="cancel()">
        Cancel
      </button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```